# Maven root pom.xml insert file conten

Tags: java, maven

Is there any possibility to inject parameters into root pom.xml of project from another file?

Maybe there something like "include" parameter?

Comment: Please write your question in a better way and try to put the things you have done and the problems you found.

Comment: You may want to read about parent POMs and `<scope>import</scope>`.

Comment: what you want is not clear! look how to ask a good question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to include a POM in another POM, you need to create the POM to include, first.

In order to do this, create a new maven project without `src/main` and `srv/test` and change `<packaging>jar</packaging>` to `<packaging>pom</packaging>`.

Write everything you want to include in that pom.xml and publish it to a maven repository.

After that, you can include it as a parent project or a pom dependency:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>include.pom.group-id</groupId>
    <artifactId>include-pom-artifacr-id</artifactId>
    <version>YOUR_VERSION</version>
</parent>
```

or

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>include.pomgroup-id</groupId>
    <artifactId>include-pom-artifacr-id</artifactId>
    <version>YOUR_VERSION</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```